# Unit testing constructor injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, constructor, constructor-injection

Suppose that my `Foo` class has the following:

```
readonly IService service;

public Foo(IService service) 
{
    if (service == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

    this.service = service;
}

public void Start()
{
    service.DoStuff();
}
```

So far, I have one unit test for the constructor where I pass in null to verify that an `ArgumentNullException` gets thrown. Do I need a second unit test for my constructor where I pass in a valid `IService` and verify that `this.service` gets set (which would require a public accessor)?

Or should I just rely on my unit test for the `Start` method to test this code path?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting `this.service` is an implementation detail, so you should just be testing that it is used where expected and just test this via the `Start` method. Lest your tests become brittle.

You only want to test that your service is used appropriately. You shouldn't care how it is stored.

Answer (score 10):

These tests are redundant, since no other test will succeed when your constructor doesn't work.

And to be honest, I don't even bother to write those null checks in my constructors anymore. Reason is simple: DI containers don't allow you to auto-wire constructors with null references (or at least, not by default), so there is no possibility of types being constructed using null values (when auto-wired by a container). So it just adds useless code that makes me add useless tests when I want to have high code coverage.

I say skip these null checks completely and trust your DI container (or pick a DI container that you can trust).